# Why bash not printing PS1 variable?

Tags: c, bash

I want to create remote bash (by tcp socket) and i wrote this code:

```
// servfd is descriptor  to server socket
int sockfd = accept(servfd,&addr,sizeof(addr));
dup2(sockfd,fileno(stdin));
dup2(sockfd,fileno(stdout));
dup2(sockfd,fileno(stderr));
setenv("PS1","# ",1);
execl("/system/bin/sh","sh",NULL);
```

And prompt wasn't printed to socket, but when I send a command etc: 'echo test' it's working but no prompt printing.

I have found a solution i must use /dev/ptmx

Comment: Can i print PS1 with sh?

Comment: Yes, you can. To do so you need to `export PS1`. However, the `sh` prompt is not as fancy as the `bash` prompt, so your `bash` PS1 may not result in the same prompt when used in `sh`.

Comment: Your `sh` is _probably_ a link to `dash`. (See what `file $(which sh)` prints). If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27755138/4014959) has some useful info.

Comment: I have linked sh to mksh, I using an Android to test because i want to create a daemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT again: I was being stupid. The problem is that the shell is not interactive because `std(in|out|err)` are not ttys anymore. Use

```
execl("/system/bin/sh", "sh", "-i", "NULL");

// along with the fork dance from below  if you want to continue with the main
// program after this
```

to force `mksh` to be interactive, in which case it should print a prompt to `stderr` every time. This will also make `mksh` interpret `~/.mkshrc`, where `PS1` is probably set. If it is not set there, you'll still have to export `PS1`, and the problems with `system()` remain. If it is set there,

```
system("sh -i");
```

#### Old, possibly obsolete part of answer:

EDIT: There's a little more at work here than I first suspected. `system()` discards environment variables along the way to its subshell. This has something to do with the fact that it runs (in this case)

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "sh", NULL);
```

(that is to say, it can be reproduced even with an `export`ed `PS1` by running `sh -c sh`). I am not quite sure why `sh -c sh` discards `PS1`; it does not do that for other environment variables.

It is possible to mimic the `system()` call in this case without that effect by using `fork` and `exec`, as shown in the code below. However, `PS1` will still need to be `export`ed for subprocesses to see it.

So, the reasons of this are most likely that `PS1` is not `export`ed and `system()` discards things. Run this piece of code to check and spawn the shell with `PS1` inherited if available:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  pid_t pid;
  char const *ps1 = getenv("PS1");

  if(ps1 != NULL) {
    puts(ps1);
  } else {
    puts("PS1 is NULL");
  }

  pid = fork();
  if(pid == -1) {
    fputs("fork broke. Aborting.\n", stderr);
    return -1;
  } else if(pid == 0) {
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", NULL);
  } else {
    wait(NULL);
  }

  puts("Continuing here after the shell exited.");

  return 0;
}
```

For me, this prints `PS1 is NULL` and opens a shell with a default `PS1` if `PS1` is not exported and keeps the prompt if I run it again after `export PS1`.

`export` makes the difference between shell variables and environment variables. If you want subprocesses to inherit a shell variable, make it an environment variable by `export`ing it.